# about ipython expected an indented block

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

How to remove this error? I don't have any idea I try everything.

Comment: Can you show what I need to change? @MatinaG

Comment: 4 spaces in for lines plt.scatter to plt.legend

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error as mentioned: you need to add 4 spaces left of `plt.`, for all lines in your `for` loop

Comment: not all lines aclually: I guess he wants to plot one time, not 4